# Is there a way to have a fraction rounded up to the next fractional value?

Tags: java, currency, fractions

I'm trying to create a Money Maker that based on the user's input it gathers how much you need of each cent.

Gold Coins = .10 , Silver = .05 & Bronze = .01

I've tried a couple of things to debug my code and notices when my remainder fraction is close to a number it will give me a bug
e.g. user inputs .65 when using .65 % .10 i get .049999999... hence when going through the silver value it doesn't take it into consideration and just pushes it out to the bronze coins.

```java
System.out.println("What amount would you like to convert");

String stringInput = userInput.readLine();

double amountToConvert = Double.parseDouble(stringInput);

double goldValue = .10;
double goldCoins = Math.floor(amountToConvert / goldValue);
double remainder = amountToConvert % goldValue; // here if a value is super close to, and it will not round it and pass it over to Bronze coins incorrectly.

double silverValue = .05;
remainder = remainder % silverValue;
```

I've already tried Math.ceil and it just rounds up the fraction as a whole and that's not what I need.

Comment: Do not use floating point number types like `float` or `double` for money values. Work with "cent" values instead by using `int` or `long` types.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be your direct answer. But as an alternative you can simply work with integer values between 1 to 100. If you need can divide results to 100.

User input 65 leads 6 gold and 1 silver.

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("What amount would you like to convert");
        String stringInput = "65";

        int amountToConvert = Integer.parseInt(stringInput);


        int goldValue = 10;
        int goldCoins = amountToConvert / goldValue;
        System.out.println(goldCoins);
        int remainder = amountToConvert % goldValue; // here if a value is super close to, and it will not round it and pass it over to Bronze coins incorrectly.

        //System.out.println(remainder);

        int silverValue = 5;
        remainder = remainder / silverValue;
        System.out.println(remainder);
    }
```